# Nokogiri unable to find XPath beginning with "("

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I have to use the following XPath:

```
(//li[@id='result_0']//span[contains(@class,'s-price')])[2]
```

My code looks like this:

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get(site_url)
element = page.at("(//li[@id='result_0']//span[contains(@class,'s-price')])[2]")
```

Firebug is able to find the element using the same XPath, but when I use this XPath in Nokogiri, I get the following error:

```
Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError: unexpected '(' after ''
from /home/shubham/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/css/parser_extras.rb:87:in `on_error'
from /home/shubham/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/racc/parser.rb:258:in `_racc_do_parse_c'
from /home/shubham/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/racc/parser.rb:258:in `do_parse'
from /home/shubham/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/css/parser_extras.rb:62:in `parse'
from /home/shubham/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/css/parser_extras.rb:79:in `xpath_for'
from /home/shubham/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/css.rb:23:in `xpath_for'
from /home/shubham/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/searchable.rb:198:in `block in xpath_query_from_css_rule'
from /home/shubham/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/searchable.rb:197:in `map'
from /home/shubham/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/searchable.rb:197:in `xpath_query_from_css_rule'
from /home/shubham/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/searchable.rb:52:in `block in search'
from /home/shubham/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/searchable.rb:51:in `map'
from /home/shubham/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/searchable.rb:51:in `search'
from /home/shubham/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/searchable.rb:67:in `at'
from (irb):11
from /home/shubham/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Comment: my question was how to resolve the above issue, which is now resolved thanks to @alecxe

Comment: Just because Firebug or any other browser-based plugin can see something doesn't mean that a node exists. Browsers do a lot of things, including HTML fixups and processing JavaScript, that a parser won't or can't do because they're very different beasts. A plugin, like Firefox, relies on the HTML source presented by the browser, after it has messed with the source, and a parser does it without fixups or DHTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError:

Judging by the error, you are trying to use an XPath expression inside the `css` method which expects a CSS selector instead. Use `xpath()` method.

Comment: thanks, i was using `page.at`, the problem got resolved on using `page.at_xpath`

Comment: `at`, like the generic `search` tries to use some heuristics to determine whether the selector passed in is CSS or XPath, then they'll call the appropriate CSS or XPath variant of `at_css`, `at_xpath`, `css` or `xpath`. The majority of the time I rely on the generic `at` or `search` and it does the right thing. Occasionally it'll mess up because the selector is nebulous or confusing and I'll have to use the specific method.